# Locale settings for virtualenv on windows

Tags: django, python-3.x, datetime, virtualenv, locale

I have 2 virtual environments and I'm working with DJANGO 1.10.1 on Windows. I get an error for datetime.strptime objects formatted as '%c' on only one - I'm testing with this file - test-py.py

```
import re, datetime
from django.utils.timezone import utc

def GetDate(date_str=None):
    date_str = "created on Thu Oct 28 08:27:43 2017 - by user bla@bla.com"
    pattern = re.compile('[a-z-A-Z]{3}\s[a-z-A-Z]{3}\s*\d* [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}')
    created_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(re.findall(pattern, date_str)[0], '%c').replace(tzinfo=utc)
    return created_date
```

This code works on one virtualenv but not on the other - and returns an error. At first I thought that it was the python locale, so I checked locale in python for virtual ENV 1 (tools):

```
(tools) C:\xeb\django_tools>python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('da_DK', 'cp1252')
```

The return of the test-py.py script on the *Tools* env is

```
(tools) C:\xeb\django_tools>python test-py.py
2017-10-28 08:27:43+00:00
```

Virtual ENV 2 - (tools2)

```
(tools2) C:\xeb\django_tools>python
Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:25:23) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('da_DK', 'cp1252')
```

The return of the test-py.py script on the *Tools2* env is

```
(tools2) C:\xeb\django_tools>python test-py.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test-py.py", line 14, in <module>
print(GetInfo())
File "test-py.py", line 8, in GetInfo
created_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(re.findall(pattern, test_str)[0], '%c').replace(tzinfo=utc)
File "C:\Python34\Lib\_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "C:\Python34\Lib\_strptime.py", line 337, in _strptime
(data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Thu Oct 28 08:27:43 2017' does not match format '%c'
```

EDIT:

In DJANGO 1.10.1 - the TIME_ZONE setting is set to UTC. After reading the comments below, I checked the LC_TIME variable in the python shell and in the interactive shell that loads the django settings - in each case and in both environents

```
locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)
```

returns

```
(None, None)
```

Changing the TIME_ZONE setting to anything else still returns None.

So why does the same code return a match format error for '%c' in only one environment.

Comment: Can you show us `locale.getlocale(category=locale.LC_TIME)` in both environments?

Comment: Hi - locale.getlocale(category=locale.LC_TIME) returns a tuple (None, None) in both environments.